# readline only print half of the results in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, nlp, readline

As titled, I have a csv file with 6 columns. For NLP processing I need to extract the 6th column(which is a review comment column) and transform it to a list of list of words using NLP.The code below is given by the instructor：

```
def read_twitter(fname):
    """ Read the given dataset into list and clean stop words. 
    
    Args: 
        fname (string): filename of Twitter Dataset
        
    Returns:
        list of list of words: we view each document as a list, including a list of all words 
    """
    twitter = []
    with open(fname,encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for line in f:
            tweet = f.readline().split(",")[5]
            
            # YOUR CLEANING CODE HERE
            #    - Clean tweet
            #    - Split into list words
            #    - Store list in twitter
            
    return twitter
```

Then we call the function read_twitter:

```
twitter = read_twitter('twitter.csv')
```

It should return some list of lists as required. However, with no codes added to the above part,I'm sure it should return an empty list.But it gives the following error:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15784\2512851317.py in read_twitter(fname)

```
 12         for line in f:

 13
```

---> 14             tweet = f.readline().split(",")[5]

```
 15 

 16
```

IndexError: list index out of range.

But when I tried to edit the above code and change it to:

```
def read_twitter(fname):
    """ Read the given dataset into list and clean stop words. 
    
    Args: 
        fname (string): filename of Twitter Dataset
        
    Returns:
        list of list of words: we view each document as a list, including a list of all words 
    """
    twitter = []
    with open(fname,encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for line in f:
            print(f.readline().split(",")[5])
            
    return twitter
twitter = read_twitter('twitter.csv')
```

It actually has the result but includes only half rows of the dataset. I am quite confused on how this readline() function is doing here and why it kept saying out of range. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The code you are given is buggy. Iterating over a file *already* calls `readline` implicitly via the file-like object's `__next__` method. There is no reason to call `readline` explicitly unless your goal is to read two lines of the file per iteration. When `__next__` reaches the end of the file, the loop handles the `StopIteartion` exception it raises. When you call `readline` explicitly, *you* need to deal with the possibility that the string it returns is empty (leading to `split` returning a list too short to have a 6th element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are skipping lines by combining a file iteration and readline. `for line in f:` iterates one line then `tweet = f.readline().split(",")[5]` reads the next. Just remove the readline.

```
def read_twitter(fname):
    """ Read the given dataset into list and clean stop words. 
    
    Args: 
        fname (string): filename of Twitter Dataset
        
    Returns:
        list of list of words: we view each document as a list, including a list of all words 
    """
    twitter = []
    with open(fname,encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for line in f:
            tweet = line.split(",")[5]
            
            # YOUR CLEANING CODE HERE
            #    - Clean tweet
            #    - Split into list words
            #    - Store list in twitter
            
    return twitter
```